# Best Way to Change a String in a Wordpress Post

Tags: php

I have a date value inside a WordPress post's content that I need to be replaced every day with the current day.

The string looks like this: **2017-11-11 00:00**

I was thinking of building a simple PHP script that would access the MySql wp_posts and find/replace that string, then run the update SQL query to change the required value.

```
$pattern = '/201\d{1}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s00:00/';
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$replacement = "$today '00:00'";
$finalString = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $originalString);
```

The post content doesn't change so the regexp doesn't need to be more elaborated than this and also the hour:mins can remain 00:00

Now the ugly part is that I will need to run a chron job, once per day to run this PHP that updates the SQL database.

Is there a better/safer/easier way to solve this issue?

Comment: you can do this with a shortcode. in the content you insert e.g. `[currentDay]` and you generate the shortcode as explained here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: This sounds good but how do I increment the shortcode every day with a new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new shortcode with this code

```
add_shortcode("currentDay", function ($attr, $content, $tag) {

    $date = current_time("Y-m-d");

    return $date;

});
```

and you just have to put `[currentDay]` in the content